# Programmable frequency source for microprocessor interrupt

Tags: arduino, frequency

I need to interrupt an Arduino at one of three chosen rates: 2400, 2000, 1920 per sec.

Given a 16MHz master clock and 16-bit timers, it doesn't look possible to do this internally (16Mhz / 2400 = 6666.666), no matter the prescaler, and anyway, an Arduino resonator isn't very precise. So I'm looking for an external module.

A 48KHz TCXO could be evenly divided by each of the rates, but I don't know A) if I can buy such a thing, and B) how to programmatically divide its output by 20, 24 or 25 (or select one of three pre-divided outputs).

Is there a solution I'm missing? Or do I have to build this from scratch (not really in my wheelhouse)?

Comment: Can you tell us what Arduino you use, more specifically if you can add or change quartz on board?

Comment: How accurately you must hit a specific rate and what tolerance is allowed? Is it OK if the average frequency is ideal so it's OK to have 2400 pulses per second even if some pulses are one clock cycle faster or slower, or must each pulse be ideal?

Comment: Choose an Arduino compatible board that has the desired characteristics. As Justme comments - what precision do you require? Any solution you choose will have a degree of error - you need to understand the amount of error you can tolerate and design your solution around that.

Comment: @Rokta - It should be Nano form factor, so either that or something like a Teensy if that would help.

Comment: @Justme - I need to hit the mark as closely as possible, so much better than the 100+ ppm tolerance of the typical resonator. I'm almost convinced that I'll need an external freq standard to get there, but I'm open.

Comment: @Kartman - Do you know of some compatible that could achieve those exact frequencies through internal timers etc? I'll look at anything but I can't afford 1% tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

There are off-the-shelf quartz crystals especially designed for: 1200 bps, 2400 bps, 4800 bps, 9600 bps, 19200 bps bit rates.

You may find those quartz crystals in the range of:  3.xyz MHz, 7.xyx MHz, 14.xyz MHz

Take a look here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator_frequencies

Comment: Are you suggesting substituting for the xtal or resonator on the micro? If so, do you know how I can achieve all three of those freqs using a particular clone and xtal?

Comment: 25 MHz is prime with 24 MHz therefore there isn't an xtal frequency that makes happy both. You will always have a small error.

Comment: Actually, a standard xtal of 18.432 MHz divides evenly by 2400, 2000 and 1920, and that should be within the range of an Arduino clone. I'd have to find a tutorial on how to change the xtal and adapt the bootloader (or whatever needs adapting). But the precision still troubles me.